# GCP Rename db name mannually and add to terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created a DB via Terraform and after that, I have removed and created it again with another name.

And when I changed the DB name in Terraform it says that:

```
Error: Error creating Database: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: failed to create database YYY. Detail: pq: database "YYY" already exists., invalid
```

I have restored a backup file and don't want to remove and recreate again via Terraform.
Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> I have removed and created it again with another name.

Did you do that manually or using Terraform? In case you did it manually, try importing `YYY` database to the terraform state using `terraform import`. More info [here](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import).